# Vanishing Blocks/Menues

Tags: routes, blocks, theming

I have a legacy site running Drupal 6.19, and today, I found out that the entire side bar had disappeared. I haven't run any updates, and no administrators have been on the site for a while, so I'm not sure what could have triggered this. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to reverse this?

I have gone into the /build/blocks menu, and the proper menu items are listed as being there (right sidebar region), and if I add a test item to any block region, it won't show up. The site is using a custom theme; however, the issue persists if I change themes the the default Drupal theme. I didn't see anything in the theme or global theme configs that would indicate a problem.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Do you have a functioning version of the site anywhere else? If so you could do an rsync -cvrn to check the files haven't been altered. Also I would be looking at tailing some logs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by my collegue when he MySQL. Unfortunately, I didn't find any errors displayed on screen or in the logs, so I'm not sure what happened.